# Legacy web apps - Determining forward compatibility with modern browsers?

Tags: asp.net, testing, web-applications, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

We have over 200 web applications. They are used both internally and by our external employees. Our company's standard has been IE8. We are planning on changing that and adopting IE 10 or 11.

Also, our external employees may use the application in their preferred browser (FF, Opera, Safari, diff. versions, etc.).

I know of services such as [browershots](http://browsershots.org/), but these are mostly to check if layout is consistent across browsers and tell you nothing if the functionality is still working or not. Is there any other way to do an efficient preliminary check for compatibility with newer browsers instead of having to do a full out regression test? If checks fail, the regression tests can follow and then refactoring what is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We can use  tools like Citrix AppDNA or modern.ie and IECT tool as a  combination to explore the strategy and update the applications

Comment: some notes on how to use the tools would be useful to the person asking the question